# Should tags for genres and other literary terms consistently be in singular form?

Tags: discussion, tags

After noticing the tag [sonnets](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sonnets) on a question about Shakespeare's sonnet 90, I was not sure whether it referred to Shakespeare's sonnets (in which case [sonnets-shakespeare](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sonnets-shakespeare) would be recommended) or the sonnet as a genre. So I looked at how names of genres and literary terms in general had been spelled in tags so far and found the following (non-exhaustive lists):

- In singular: [haiku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haiku), [manhua](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manhua), [title](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/title), [translation](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation), [publication](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publication), [genre](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genre), [moral](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moral), [theme](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme), [biography](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biography), [plot-element](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-element), [timeline](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timeline).
- In plural:  [short-stories](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-stories), [mystery-novels](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mystery-novels), [myths](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myths), [fairy-tales](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fairy-tales), [folk-tales](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folk-tales), [video-games](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games), [illustrators](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/illustrators), [adaptations](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adaptations), [origins](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins), [apocryphal-works](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apocryphal-works).

([comics](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics) is a [plurale tantum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum), so I didn't add it to the lists.)

There are several approaches we can take to this:

- Leave it as is; folksonomies are messy, so learn to live with it.
- Make the plural form the preferred form. (But see the ambiguity of [sonnets](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sonnets) above).
- Make the singular form the preferred form.

I am in favour of consistently using the singular form and I am willing to do the necessary retagging work if we decide to go that way.

Comment: I don't think we need a *sonnets-shakespeare* tag. Anything tagged both *sonnets* and *shakespeare* is probably about Shakespeare's sonnets.

Answer (score 2):

I've been thinking about this one for a couple days, since you posted it, and I've gotta be honest with you... I just don't see a reason to care, in general. I know there's that little niggling voice that says, "hey, this all is not done in the same way." But there's another voice asking, "does it really matter?" And I can't answer to that one. Also, at least to me, some of the plurals just sound better. The singulars aren't wrong, but "apocryphal work" sounds a little odd to my ears.

I like to think people will pick whichever one feels better by default, on the whole. That may not be consistent but it might be good enough - like you say, folksonomies are messy. That said, if there's a specific case that's causing confusion (I can imagine a hypothetical) or obviously sounds wrong (like if someone made the tag "paparazzo" on Photography), then sure, let's change that.

(*Also gotta point out: haiku is also plural!)

Answer (score -1):

**Tags can be messy but can typically be left alone.**

It is not the form that matters but how the tag is defined by its wiki and excerpt.

Proper usage guidance should be able to clear up any questions if a tag is being applied properly or not.

If any tag is consistently being misused and has a sufficient definition it might be time to raise a tag specific meta to either rename, create a synonym , or take other appropriate action.